# tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath: not working

Tags: ios5, nsmutablearray, tableview

So, in my viewDidLoad method I called:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

Then later on in my tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath: I do this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {   
    [self.list removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

}

But when I delete a row in my tableView, while actually running the app, I get an exception thrown on the removeObjectAtIndex call to my list. I tried taking that out, but then I get another exception thrown on the tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:

Please help!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.list` needs to be an `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: are you sure an object is present at that index?